# VB.NET Sqlite DBNull excception

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am having a problem here, but I don't see where I went wrong.

The thing is that I do insert a valid integer value during the Insert, but when I retrieve the value, I get a DBNull exception in this line:

```
iTestValue = rTest("myscore")
```

The full code reads:

```
    Dim nCn As SQLiteConnection
    ncn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:")
    ncn.Open()

    Dim cmdCreate1 As New SQLiteCommand(nCn)
    cmdCreate1.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE mytable (mytext TEXT,myscore INTEGER)"
    cmdCreate1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmdCreate1.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX idx_mytable_myscore ON mytable (myscore)"
    cmdCreate1.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim nTA As SQLiteTransaction
    nTA = nCn.BeginTransaction

    Dim nCmdIns As New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO mytable (mytext,myscore) VALUES (?,?)", nCn)

    Dim l&
    For l = 1 To UBound(uNPhones)
        nCmdIns.Parameters.Clear()
        nCmdIns.Parameters.Add(ExpandCat(uNPhones(l).Text), DbType.String)
        nCmdIns.Parameters.Add(uNPhones(l).Score, DbType.Int32)
        nCmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next l

    nTA.Commit()

    Dim nSelTest As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable", nCn)
    Dim rTest As SQLiteDataReader
    rTest = nSelTest.ExecuteReader

    Dim iCountTest As Integer
    iCountTest = 0

    Do While rTest.Read
        Dim iTestValue As Integer
        iTestValue = rTest("myscore")
        Dim sTestValue As String
        sTestValue = rTest("mytext")
        iCountTest += 1
    Loop
```

Comment: Don't add the parameter inside the loop; change the parameter value inside the loop. Make sure you're assigning the parameter value. You can add the parameter  (giving it a name) and datatype, and then in a separate step set the value of the parameter. You can also use named parameters in SQLite.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx